# Insertion sort - Average case complexity worked example to prove formula for average case

Tags: big-o, insertion-sort

I am confused as to why my worked example for average case for insertion sort is very different to the formula I found for calculating the average case.

The insertion sort code I am using is below.

```
int[] myNumbers = {1, 2 3, 4};      
    int j;
    int key;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < myNumbers.length ; i++){
        j = i - 1;
        key = myNumbers[i];

        while (j >= 0 && myNumbers[j] > key) {        
            myNumbers[j + 1] = myNumbers[j];
            j--;
        }
        myNumbers[j+1] = key;
    }
```

Assuming you want to sort four values: 1, 2 3, 4 and every permutation of inputs is equally likely, the number of comparisons for each possible input is as follows:

```
3 comparisons for inputs 1234, 2134 
4 comparisons for inputs 1243, 1324, 2143, 2314, 3124, 3214 
5 comparisons for inputs 1342, 1423, 2341, 2413, 3142, 3241, 4123, 4213 
6 comparisons for inputs 1432, 2431, 3412, 3421, 4132, 4231, 4312, 4321
```

The average would then be = (3 * 2) + (4 * 6) + (5 * 8) + (6 * 8) / 24
= 4.9166666

But the formula I found for calculating the average number of comparisons was 
 (n^2 - n) / 4 which gives 3 which can't be right?  3 is the best case.

I see that the average case is calculated as half the worst case which I think is the right way of working it out.  Is it just my small set that's producing unexpected results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!